# SmartThings Hub and Nest Thermostat

Tags: samsung-smartthings, nest-thermostat

Is it currently possible to link a Nest thermostat with the Samsung SmartThings Hub?

The Nest is not available in the list of thermostats to add, within the SmartThings App. However, is there at least a SmartApp that allow a bit more automation?

If not, is there a newsletter or RSS feed to let me know when Nest might be supported?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [SmartThings's Support Page](https://support.smartthings.com/hc/en-us/articles/204733384-Does-SmartThings-work-with-Nest-):

> SmartThings doesn’t officially support Nest at this time, but many users instead utilize a custom integration created by a developer in the SmartThings Developer Community. This integration reportedly works well, and you can set it up through the [SmartThings IDE](http://ide.smartthings.com/) by [following the steps here](https://community.smartthings.com/t/release-nest-manager-4-0/60052).

In other words, it isn't officially supported, but it appears that it can work. [Ifttt.com](https://ifttt.com/connect/nest_thermostat/smartthings) claims to have designed an applet which connects these two.